# Is it possible to model/estimate the tilt angle of a motorbike using the iphone accelerometer/gyroscope?

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer, gyroscope

How can i use the yaw/pitch/roll to estimate the tilt angle of a motorbike, assuming the iphone is in the pocket. I'm thinking along the lines of storing the baseline yaw/pitch/roll when the user begins riding in the upright position then any deviation from that will give me rotations about all 3 axis, but how do i use this to figure out the lateral tilt angle of a motorbike? Thanks.

Comment: You would have to figure out the heading first but it seems difficult to do that reliably. You can easily create heuristics for that but it is just a matter of time the heuristics fail in a corner case.